# Icon missing in Windows 10 Start menu search when Installer is signed

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, windows-10, signtool

I'm building an msi installer for my application with WIX.  The icon shows up correctly for the shortcut installed to the start menu.  When I type in the name of the application in the start menu search bar, the search results include my application, but the icon is a generic one from windows.

This seems inconsistent, but usually the unsigned msi works fine (the icon shows up), but the signed msi has the issue.

Here's one more data point - if I create a new user on the computer the application (having been installed for all users) shows up AND the icon is correct when the start menu is searched.

For what it's worth, I'm using visual studio integration to build the installer.

The application itself is a .Net executable written in C#, with some native dependencies.

The application is obfuscated using crypto obfuscator.

Note there's a separate localized resources dll to enable the shortcot to have localized text.  It's not clear if this could or should affect the icon

Here's the wxs.  I know it's far from exemplary, and I'm open to any improvement suggestions, but prefer to focus on the issue at hand:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Product Id="*" Name="my name by foo" Language="1033" Codepage="UTF-8" Version="!(bind.FileVersion.barControlPanel)" Manufacturer="foo inc" UpgradeCode="guid1">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Description="Version: !(bind.FileVersion.barControlPanel)"/>


    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="Cab1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <SetProperty Id="ARPINSTALLLOCATION" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" After="CostFinalize"/>

    <util:CloseApplication Id="CloseApp" CloseMessage="yes" Target="foo.barControlPanel.exe"/>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="myapptitle by foo" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut"/>
    </Feature>

    <Icon Id="myfoobar.ico" SourceFile="..\myfoobar.ico"/>

    <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="myfoobar.ico"/>
    <Property Id="ARPNOREPAIR" Value="yes" Secure="yes" />
    <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="yes" Secure="yes" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="foo_InstallCheck" Before="LaunchConditions"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

 </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id="foo_InstallCheck" BinaryKey="foo_InstallCheckBinary" DllEntry="CustomAction1" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
    <Binary Id="foo_InstallCheckBinary" SourceFile="$(var.foo.InstallCheck.TargetDir)$(var.foo.InstallCheck.TargetName)$(var.foo.InstallCheck.TargetExt)"/>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="fooinc" Name="foo inc">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="barControlPanel">
          <Directory Id="ja" Name="ja"/>
        </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="DATAFOLDER" Name="foo inc"/>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents">
      <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
      <Component Id="ProductComponent" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
        <File Id="barControlPanel" Source="$(var.ObfuscationProject.TargetDir)foo.barControlPanel.exe" >     
          <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
                  DescriptionResourceDll="[#foobarControlPanelResources]"
                  DescriptionResourceId="101"
                  DisplayResourceDll="[#foobarControlPanelResources]"
                  DisplayResourceId="101"
                   Directory="ProgramMenuFolder"
                  Name="my app by foo"
                  WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
           Icon="myfoobar2.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes">
          <Icon Id="myfoobar2.ico" SourceFile="..\myfoobar.ico"/>
        </Shortcut>
        </File>
        <File Id="fooHelp.pdf" Source="..\fooHelp.pdf"/>
        <File Id="fooHelp.ja.pdf" Source="..\fooHelp.ja.pdf"/>
        <File Id="foobarControlPanelResources" Source="$(var.foo.barControlPanel.Resources.TargetDir)foo.barControlPanel.Resources.dll"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Resources" Directory="ja">
        <File Id="JapaneseResources" Source="$(var.ObfuscationProject.TargetDir)ja\foo.barControlPanel.Resources.dll"/>
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="GUID2">
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\foo inc\my app" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```